# "Ich miete eine Wohnung" bedeutet "ich bezahle für eine Wohnung" oder "ich bekomme Geld dafür"? Oder beides?

Tags: verb, meaning

Vielleicht ist es mit den Objekten einfacher zu verstehen, aber bedeutet der Satz

> Ich miete eine Wohnung.

1. "Ich bezahle für eine Wohnung"
   oder
2. "Ich bekomme Geld dafür"?

Wenn die Antwort „Beide” lautet, hat dann dieses grammatische Phänomen einen bestimmten Namen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Mieten* kann nur die eine Bedeutung haben (dafür zahlen, daß man ein Objekt benutzen darf). Das Gegenstück ist *vermieten*.

Anders ist es bei *leihen*, *ausleihen* und auch bei dem umgangssprachlichen, gleichbedeutenden *borgen*, das kann beide Bedeutungen haben:

> Anna leiht Bastian ihr Auto.
>   Bastian leiht Annas Auto.
>   Bastian leiht sich von Anna ihr Auto.

Das ist also anders als im Englischen, wo *lend/loan* und *borrow* unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben.

Eindeutig ist dagegen  wieder *verleihen*:

> Anna verleiht ihr Auto.

Verben wie *mieten* und *vermieten*, die gewissermaßen denselben Vorgang von unterschiedlichen Enden betrachten, heißen *konvers*. Für Fälle wie *leihen* kenne ich keinen bestimmten Begriff.

Comment: Darf ich "Autoantiverb" vorschlagen? Wikipedia: "Sind sämtliche additiven Quantenzahlen eines Teilchens Null, so ist das Teilchen sein eigenes Antiteilchen. Dies ist z.B. der Fall beim Photon, beim Z0 und beim neutralen Pion π0."

Comment: "Für Fälle wie leihen kenne ich keinen bestimmten Begriff." -> Das wäre doch eine schöne erste Frage von dir.

Comment: @Em1: Na ja, die Frage hat c.p. hiermit ja schon gestellt …

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, wie die 3 Beispiele beide Bedeutungen haben können.

Comment: @Robert: Möglicherweise ein Mißverständnis – ich meine nicht, daß jedes der drei Beispiele beide Bedeutungen haben könnte; vielmehr illustrieren die drei Beispiele gemeinsam, daß *leihen* beide Richtungen ausdrücken kann.

Comment: Ah, ok, danke, jetzt ist es klarer.

Answer (score 8):

Die richtige Antwort ist 1. [mieten](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/mieten) => *Ich bezahle für eine Wohnung*.

*[Vermieten](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/vermieten)* wäre das Gegenteil: *Ich vermiete meine Wohnung (und bekomme dafür Geld von jemandem)*.

Comment: ach so! sowie `kaufen` und `verkaufen`.

Answer (score 5):

Da auf Spanisch, meiner Muttersprache, mieten und vermieten übereinstimmen, habe ich diese Frage gleichzeitig auf [Spanisch](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/rento-departamento-does-it-mean-pago-or-cobro-por-vivir-ahi-or-both) gestellt (na, dort habe ich eher nach dem Namen des Phänomens gefragt). In der gleichen Frage, als Kommentar, wurde die deutlich ältere [englische Version](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74342/how-to-avoid-ambiguity-in-i-am-renting-an-apartment-in-new-york) empfohlen. Dort wurde nach den unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen des Satzes *"I am renting an apartment in New York"* gefragt.

Wenn jemand sich dafür interessiert, die Antwort lautet "enantiosemy" auf English, und auf Deutsch [Januswort](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Januswort). *Antiantonym* wäre vielleicht aber ein deutlicherer Begriff.

Comment: +1 für die, in den anderen Antworten fehlende, Begriffsklärung.